# How to stop my Tumblr posts from overflowing?

Tags: html, overflow, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Specific posts on my Tumblr page keep bleeding into to the theme background. It is only happening with posts that include both images and text, however not with each one of them. I've tried everything I could to fix it but it has only made it worse.

I have also tried changing my overflow tag to hidden from visible but all it does is cut off the overflowed part instead of stopping the overflow.

This is what it looks like:

[text overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNuzH.png)

[image overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNfAp.png)

Here are the codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 
<!-- Theme by conkersradfurday, massively edited from destroyer's theme
-->
 
<html>
<head>
 
<!-- DEFAULT COLORS -->
<meta name="color:Background" content="#e5e5e5"/>
<meta name="color:center background" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:post" content="#f9d6b6"/>
<meta name="color:sidebar" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:interests title" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:sidebox" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:sidebox border" content="#6699cc"/>
<meta name="color:sidebox left" content="#B0CFF0"/>
<meta name="color:sidebox right" content="#D3E7FB"/>
<meta name="color:sidebox bold:" content="#39658c"/>
 
 
<meta name="color:Orange Text" content="#ff6600"/>
<meta name="color:Orange Background" content="#ffcc99"/>
 
<meta name="color:Text" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:text headers" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:bold text" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:label background" content="#f4f4f4"/>
<meta name="color:link" content="#003399"/>
<meta name="color:link hover" content="#cc0000"/>
<meta name="color:notes" content="#464646"/>
<meta name="color:notes hover" content="#949494"/>
<meta name="color:nav link" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:nav link hover" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:nav background" content="#6697cf"/>
<meta name="color:header background" content="#003399"/>
<meta name="color:asker background" content="#FF9933"/>
 
<meta name="text:Sex" content="Female"/>
<meta name="text:Age" content="15 Years Old"/>
<meta name="text:City" content="Hollywood"/>
<meta name="text:Country" content="California"/>
<meta name="text:Music" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Movies" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Tv" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Books" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Heroes" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Headline" content="I'm back<br>on MySpace!"/>
 
<meta name="text:Background Size" content="25%" />
 
 
<meta name="text:Profile Song" content="http://mp3.qqkjkl.com/mp3/18/30336027.mp3" />
<meta name="text:Mood" content="Nostalgic" />
 
<meta name="text:Status" content="Single"/>
<meta name="text:Orientation" content="Bisexual"/>
<meta name="text:Ethnicity" content="r"/>
<meta name="text:Religion" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Occupation" content=""/>
 
<meta name="image:Portrait" content=""/>
<meta name="image:Background" content=""/>
 
<meta name="if:Show Infinite Scroll" content="1" />
<meta name="if:Show Photo Caption" content="1" />
 
<meta name="font:Header Title" content="'Verdana', Impact, Gadget, sans-serif, Arial, Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif" />
<meta name="font:Body" content="'verdana', arial, Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif" />
 
<meta name="text:Custom Link One" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link One Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Two" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Two Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Three" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Three Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Four" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Four Title" content="" />
 
 
<title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/o8Bku9w35/reset.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
{block:Description}
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
{/block:Description}
 
{block:IfShowInfiniteScroll}<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling/code"></script>{/block:IfShowInfiniteScroll}
 
<style type="text/css">
body{ 
margin-top:0px;
text-align:justify; 
color: {color:Text}; 
font-family: {font:Body}; 
font-size: 11px; 
line-height: 12px; 
background-color:{color:Background};
background-image:url({image:Background}); 
background-attachment: repeat; 
background-position:top left; 
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size:{text:Background Size};{text:Background Size}
}
 
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active{color: {color:link}; text-decoration:none;
font-family: {font:Body}; 
font-size: 11px; line-height:12px; }
a:hover{color: {color:link hover}; line-height:12px;}
 
#tumblr_controls{
position:fixed!important;}
 
b, strong{color: {color:bold text};
font-family: {font:Body}; 
font-size: 11px; line-height:12px;}
 
#wtf {
background-color:{color:center background};
margin-top:0px;
width:750px;
overflow: visible;
margin-left: -375px;
left:50%;
position: absolute;
padding-top:10px;
color: {color:Text}; 
font-family: {font:Body}; 
font-size: 11px;  
line-height: 12px;}
 
#entry {
background-color: {color:post};
border: 0px solid {color:post};
z-index:6;
float:right;
overflow:visible; 
width:400px;
height: auto;
padding: 6px;
margin:0px 10px 6px 0px;}
 
 
#sidebar {
position: absolute;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left:-364px;
left: 50%;
background-color:{color:sidebar};
width: 304px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;}
 
#sidebox {
border-top:20px solid {color:sidebox border};
border-left:2px solid {color:sidebox border};
border-right:2px solid {color:sidebox border};
border-bottom:2px solid {color:sidebox border};
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 0px;
background-color:{color:sidebox};
width: 300px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;}
 
#sidebox b {color:{color:sidebox bold};}
 
#info {
background-color: {color:post};
border: 0px solid {color:post};
z-index:6;
float:right;
overflow:visible; 
width:400px;
height: auto;
padding: 6px;
margin:0px 10px 6px 0px;}
 
#notes {
background-color: {color:post};
border: 0px solid {color:post};
z-index:6;
float:right;
overflow:visible; 
width:400px;
height: auto;
padding: 6px;
margin:0px 10px 6px 0px;}
 
#entry img { max-width:400px;}
p{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;}
 
#question{
overflow:SHOW;
padding-bottom:3px;
margin-bottom:3px;}
 
#askr{
display:block;
float:left;
width:33px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-right:3px;}
 
ul {
list-style: disc;
padding: 4px 0px 6px 20px;}
 
blockquote{padding:0px; padding-left:5px; margin:5px; border-left:2px solid {color:label background};}
 
blockquote img{display:block; width:100%;}
 
blockquote p{padding:0px; margin:0px;}
 
blockquote blockquote{position:relative; left:6px; margin-top:0px; margin-right:0px; padding-right:0px;}
 
#bottominfo{
padding:2px 0px 0px 0px;
display:block;}
 
.answer p{margin:0px;}
.notes img{
width:10px; 
position:relative; 
top:1px;}
 
ol.notes, .notes li{
list-style:none; 
margin:0px; 
padding:0px;}
 
small {font-size:8px; line-height:8px; letter-spacing:0px;}
big {font-family:arial black; color:{color:text}; font-size:14px;}
 
.audio {width:100%; background:black; border:0px dotted #D6D6D6;}
 
a img{border:none;}
 
.label {
color: {color:bold text};font-weight: bold; line-height:12px;} 
 
.odd {
background-color:{color:label background};}
 
 
h1 {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 12px;
font-family: verdana;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: normal;
letter-spacing: -1px;
color:{color:text headers};
text-align: left;
margin:0px;
padding-bottom:1px;}
 
h2 {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
font-family: impact;
font-weight:normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: -1px;
color:{color:text headers};
text-align:left;}
 
 
h3 {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
font-family: {font:Header Title};
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: normal;
letter-spacing: -1px;
color:{color:text headers};
text-align: left;
margin:0px;
padding-bottom:4px;}
 
 
 
h4 {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 12px;
font-family: {font:Header Title};
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: capitalize;
letter-spacing: -1px;
color: {color:Orange Text};
text-align: left;
margin:0px;
padding-bottom:4px;}
 
h5 {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 12px;
font-family: {font:Header Title};
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: capitalize;
letter-spacing: -1px;
color: {color:interests title};
text-align: left;
margin:0px;}
 
 
a.links1 {
text-align:center;
margin-top:6px;
margin-bottom:8px;
color: {color:nav link};
display: inline-block;
text-transform: capitalize;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:12px;
padding: 2px;}
 
 
a.links1:hover {
color: {color:nav link hover};}
 
 
 
#ask { 
font-size:12px;
line-height:12px;
 
padding:4px;
margin-bottom:4px;}
 
 
 
img.middle {
vertical-align:middle;
margin-bottom:3px;}
 
#notez {
margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom:4px; width:400px;}
 
#notez a {
font-family: arial; 
font-size: 9px; 
line-height: 10px;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-transform: normal;}
 
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 3px;}
 
#header1 {
padding:4px;
margin-left:328px;
margin-bottom:6px;
width:404px;
height: 12px;
background-color:{color:Orange Background};}
 
#header2 {
padding:4px;
margin-left:328px;
margin-bottom:6px;
width:404px;}
 
#header3 {
padding:4px;
margin-left:328px;
margin-bottom:6px;
width:404px;
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 2px; 
border-color:#000;}
 
#myspaceheader {
width:750px;
height:81px;
background-color:{color:header background};
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}
{CustomCSS}
 
#navigation {
width:750px;
height:30px;
background-color:{color:nav background};
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}
{CustomCSS}
</style>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/3ikgvxs/0TGl4zgpu/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 
 
</head>
 
<body>
 
<div id="myspaceheader">
 
<div align=right><a href="http://myspacerebirth.tumblr.com/theme"><font color="white">Sign Up</font></a></div>
 
<div align=center><form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form></div>
<div align=left><a href="http://myspacerebirth.tumblr.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/MKqRxyf.png" title="Join the MySpace rebirth!" /></div></a>
 
 
</div>
 
<div id="navigation">
<center>
<a href="http://{name}.tumblr.com" class="links1">Home</a> |
{block:AskEnabled}<a href="/ask" class="links1">Ask</a>{/block:AskEnabled} |
 
<a href="/archive" class="links1">Archive</a>|
 
 
{block:SubmissionsEnabled}<a href="/submit" class="links1">Submit</a>{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}|
 
{block:HasPages}
{block:Pages}
<a href="{URL}" class="links1">{Label}</a>
{/block:Pages}
{/block:HasPages}
 
{block:ifCustomLinkOneTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link One}" class="links1">{text:Custom Link One Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkOneTitle} |
 
{block:ifCustomLinkTwoTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link Two}" class="links1">{text:Custom Link Two Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkTwoTitle} |
 
{block:ifCustomLinkThreeTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link Three}" class="links1">{text:Custom Link Three Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkThreeTitle} |
 
{block:ifCustomLinkFourTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link Four}" class="links1">{text:Custom Link Four Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkFourTitle}
 
</center>
</div>
 
<div id="wtf">
 
 
<div id="sidebar">
<h3>{Title}</h3>
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<div style="clear:both;">
<div style="float:left;">
    {block:IfPortraitImage}
    <a href="http://{name}.tumblr.com"><img src="{image:Portrait}" width="200"></a>
    {/block:IfPortraitImage}
</div>
 
<div style="float:right;">
    <div style="margin-left:8px;">
        "{text:Headline}" <br> <br>
        {text:Sex} <br>
        {text:Age} <br>
        {text:City} <br>
        {text:Country} <br><br>
        <img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2lh9lgwvA1qaxq5z.gif">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
 
Last Login: <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
//-->
</script>
<br><br>
<b><color="{color:post}">Mood:</color></b> {text:mood}</a>
<br>
View My: <a href="http://{name}.tumblr.com/tagged/me"><b>Pics</b></a> | <a href="http://{name}.tumblr.com/archive"><b>Archive</b></a>
<br>
<br>
<div id="sidebox">
<div style="position:absolute; margin-top:-16px; "><h5>Contact {title}</h5></div>
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" align="left"><a href="http://tumblr.com/send/{name}"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/J4RAuTM.gif" /></a></td>
    <td width="150"><a href="http://tumblr.com/follow/{name}"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/UCOmMMp.gif"></a></a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="150" align="left"><a href="/ask"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dtwze3M.gif" /></a></td>
    <td width="150"><a href="https://www.tumblr.com/settings"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QYs8aR4.gif"></a></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div><br>
 
<br>
<br>
<div style="border:1px solid {color:sidebox border}; width:302px;">
<h1>MySpace URL:</h1>
http://{name}.tumblr.com
</div><br>
<br>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="295" height="51">
    <param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3={text:Profile Song}&amp;width=295&amp;height=51&amp;buttonwidth=54&amp;sliderwidth=40&amp;skin=http%3A//i.imgur.com/uh9op43.jpg&amp;sliderovercolor=310057&amp;buttoncolor=140014&amp;buttonovercolor=fcfcfc" />
</object>
<config>
    <param name="mp3" value="{text:Profile Song}"/>
    <param name="width" value="295"/>
    <param name="height" value="51"/>
    <param name="buttonwidth" value="54"/>
    <param name="sliderwidth" value="40"/>
    <param name="skin" value="http%3A//i.imgur.com/uh9op43.jpg"/>
    <param name="sliderovercolor" value="310057"/>
    <param name="buttoncolor" value="140014"/>
    <param name="buttonovercolor" value="fcfcfc"/>
</config>
<br><br>
 
<div id="sidebox">
<div style="position:absolute; margin-top:-16px; "><h5>{title}'s interests</h5></div>
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Music:</b></td>
    <td width="188" bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Music}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Movies:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Movies}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Television:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:TV}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Books:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Books}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Heroes:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Heroes}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div><br>
 
 
<div id="sidebox">
<div style="position:absolute; margin-top:-16px; "><h5>{title}'s Details</h5></div>
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Status:</b></td>
    <td width="188" bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Status}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Orientation:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Orientation}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Ethnicity:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Ethnicity}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Religion:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Religion}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="{color:sidebox left}"><b>Occupation:</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="{color:sidebox right}">{text:Occupation}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
 
<div id="header3"><br><br><center><b><color="{color:post}"></color><font style="font-size:16px!important;">{title} is in your extended network.</b></center><br><br></font></div>
 
<div id="header1"><h4>{title}'s Blurbs</h4></div>
 
<div id="header2">
{block:Description}<h4>About Me:</h4> {Description}<br><br>{/block:Description}
</div>
 
<div id="header1"><h4>{title}'s Posts</h4></div>
 
 
<div class="autopagerize_page_element">
{block:Posts}
<div id="entry">
 
 
{block:IndexPage}
<div id="notez">
<h1>{ShortMonth} {DayOfMonth} {Year} {12Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</h1>
<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount} Notes</a> - <a href="{Permalink}">View Post</a> - <a href="{ReblogURL}">Reblog</a>
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
 
{block:Text}<h2>{Title}</h2>{Body}{/block:Text}
 
{block:Photo} 
{block:IndexPage}
<center><a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="400" border="0"></a></center>
{block:IfShowPhotoCaption}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowPhotoCaption}
{/block:IndexPage}
 
{block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="400" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}{/block:Photo}
 
{block:Photoset}<center>{block:IndexPage}{Photoset-400}{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-400}{/block:PermalinkPage}</center>{block:PermalinkPage}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IfShowPhotoCaption}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowPhotoCaption}
{/block:Photoset}
 
{block:Quote}<h2>"{Quote}"</h2>{block:Source}{Source}{/block:Source}{/block:Quote}
 
{block:Link}<a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}><h2>{Name}</h2></a>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{/block:Link}
 
{block:Chat}
{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}
{block:Lines}
{block:Label}
<div class="{Alt}"><span class="label"><strong>{Label}</strong></span>
<span class="line">{Line}</span></div>
{/block:Label}
{/block:Lines}
{/block:Chat}
 
{block:Video}<center>{block:IndexPage}<div id="video">{Video-400}</div>{block:IfNotHidePhotoCaption}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:IfNotHidePhotoCaption}{/block:IndexPage}<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hR6o8o2.png"/>
 
{block:PermalinkPage}<div id="video">{Video-400}</div>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}</center>
{/block:Video}
 
{block:Audio}
<center><div class="audio">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div></center>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Audio}
 
{block:Answer}
<table style="border-bottom:1px solid #a0a0a0;padding-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;padding-right:30px;padding-left:30px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px" bgcolor={color:asker background}><b>{Asker}</b><br><br><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-96}"></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><strong></strong><br>{Question}</td>
</tr>
</table>
{Answer}
{/block:Answer}
</div>
 
 
{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Date}
<div id="info"><div id="bottominfo">
 
Posted: <a href="/day/{year}/{monthnumberwithzero}/{dayofmonthwithzero}">{ShortDayOfWeek} {Month} {DayOfMonth}{DayOfMonthSuffix}, {Year}</a> at {12Hour}:{Minutes}{AmPm}{block:RebloggedFrom}<br>Originally posted by <a href="{ReblogRootURL}">{ReblogRootName}</a>.{/block:RebloggedFrom}
 
{block:Photo}{block:HighRes}<br>HighRes: <a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">view</a>{/block:HighRes}{/block:Photo}
 
{block:Answer}<BR>Ask: <a href="/ask">{AskLabel}</a>{/block:Answer}
 
{block:Audio}<BR>Plays: {FormattedPlayCount}{block:ExternalAudio}<BR>Download: <a href="{ExternalAudioURL}">here</a>.{/block:ExternalAudio}{/block:Audio}
 
{block:HasTags}<BR>Tagged: {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{block:NoteCount}<BR>Notes: {NoteCount}{/block:NoteCount}
 
</div></div>
{/block:Date}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
 
 
{block:PostNotes}
<div id="notes">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
 
{/block:Posts}
 
</div> </*Infinite Scroll*/>
 
{block:Pagination}
<div id="entry">
<center> <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="200">
{block:PreviousPage}<div align="left"><a href="{PreviousPage}">◄ Previous</a></div>{/block:PreviousPage}
</td>
 
<td width="200">{block:NextPage}<div align="right"><a href="{NextPage}">Next ►</a></div>{/block:NextPage}
</td>
</tr>
</table></center>
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
 
<center><img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2lokcAnTG1qaxq5z.png" width="750" height="2"><br></center>
<center><small>©2003-<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(year)
//-->
</script> MySpace.com. Theme by conkersradfurday. All Rights Reserved.  </small></center>
 
<style type="text/css">
            ul#likes {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
                padding: 0 0 0 0;
            }
 
                li.like_post {
                    /* Should match the width specified in the Likes tag */
                    width: 150px;
                    padding: 0 40px 0 0;
                    float: left;
                }
 
                  li.like_post img {
                      max-width: 100%;
                  }
 
                  li.like_post blockquote {
                      margin: 0;
                      padding: 0 0 0 10px;
                      border-left: 1px solid #eee;
                  }
 
                  li.like_post ol,
                  li.like_post ul {
                      margin: 0 0 0 15px;
                      padding: 0;
                  }
 
                  li.like_post .like_link a {
                      font-weight: bold;
                  }
 
                  li.like_post .like_title {
                      font-weight: bold;
                  }
 
                  li.like_post .post_info_bottom {
                      margin: 10px 0 0 0;
                      display: block !important;
                  }
        </style>
 
    </head>
 
</html>
```

Comment: In your css you have multiple classes, which have `overflow` set to `visible`. Seems like you just need to find the correct class and change the `overflow` to what you want it to do.

Comment: @Geshode  I have tried changing them to hidden but all it does is hide the portion of the post that is overflowing; it still overflows but the overflowed part is cut off.

Comment: Change it to scroll or auto, so that you can use scrollbars, when it overflows. Or is that not acceptable?

Comment: @Geshode I was wondering if it could be possible for the posts to be within the constraints it is supposed to be in

Comment: Then you have to make the width of the element, which contains the text or picture smaller, so that it fits within the parent. Assuming, that the blue background is the parent. Relative values, like % or vw would be helpful for that, instead of px values.